# Bootstrap-toggle becomes large and ugly. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I try to add a bootstrap-toggle check box (http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) to my website. But when I add it, it becomes big and ugly (see [picture of my toggle and its appearance.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI9gK.png)).

Moreover, I use:

- JQuery v. 3.3.1, Bootstrap v. 4.1.3, and Bootstrap-toggle v. 2.2.0
- A local python server.
- Chrome.
- The HTML-structure below.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-toggle.min.css">
 <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
</body>

<script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**: Problem solved. It was linked to screen resolution. The buttons get large and ugly when rendered on localhost on screens with low resolution, but works well on screens with higher resolution.

Comment: Right click the checkbox element and view the associated CSS. You probably have some other CSS interfering which you need to remove or override.

Comment: If you want help from this community, please reproduce this problem using Stack Overflow snippets or JSFiddle, or similar tool.

Comment: It's because of CSS override issue. You can fix it by checking to inspect element. Or please provide working jsfiddle or codepen link to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes the CSS was overridden. Actually, the problem was linked to screen resolution. If I run my website on a screen with high resolution the toggles render perfectly well, but not on a screen with low resolution...

Answer (score 0):

If you use external links and Bootstrap v3.3.7, this works perfectly:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, the problem was linked to screen resolution. If I run my website on a screen with high resolution the toggles render perfectly well, but not on a screen with low resolution